# A simple way to compute cumulative distribution function in Python

Tags: python, statistics

I'm trying to compute the distribution function of any of the usual distributions in Python... However, all the methods I've seen involve first drawing N samples from said distribution, and then order them somehow, and then do a cumulative sum.

In Mathematica, I can just do `CDF[ChiSquaredDistribution[df],quantile]`. If I want another distribution, I just substitute `ChiSquaredDistribution` for the name of that other distribution.

Is there a simple way, like in Mathematica, to compute a cumulative distribution function in Python?

Comment: Take a look at Scipy -- I think they have cdf, pdf, quantile function, etc., for many widely-used distributiuons.

Comment: @RobertDodier Yes, they do. Thanks ;)